# Django filter from another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

In models.py I have following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=255, default='Agent')
    town = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    def __str__(self):
        return str('Advanced user informations')

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    content = HTMLField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my views.py I have:

```
def news(request):
    news_list = News.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    paginator = Paginator(news_list, 5) 
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    news = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'news.html', {'news': news})
```

Now I want to achieve that a User can only see news for a project he participates.

Something like:

```
News.objects.filter(News with a project that the User is linked to)
```

But I am not sure what could be a valid way to solve this. Maybe someone has a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this,

```
News.objects.filter(project__in=request.user.profile.project.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
News.objects.filter(project__profile_set__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Unfortunetely brings: ValueError at /news/   

Cannot query "admin": Must be "Project" instance.

Comment: This error message suggests, that you are using the `admin` user in a place where the query expects a `Project` instance. From the code above I can't see where that could happen. Did you add the above line in the `news(request)` function or somewhere else?